# How do I search bash's history in vi mode for "foo.*bar"

Tags: bash, regular-expression, command-history, readline

I have my bash environment in vi mode (`set -o vi`). So I can type `<ESC>/` followed by a word, followed by enter, and bash searches for the word in the history.
Since `/` is also vi's method to search for regular expressions, I was under the expression that bash will search for regular expressions as well.

Unfortunately, when I type `<ESC>/foo.*bar` in bash, it does not find any line in the history that matches the regular expression `foo.*bar`.

Am I overlooking something or is it just not possible to search the history for regular expressions?

Comment: This question may be better suited for [the Vi and Vim Stack Exchange Site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Paradox, but it is not really a vi question, is it?

Comment: That's how it appears to me, but I could be mistaken since it involves BASH as well.

Comment: I don't have any more supporting evidence, but [this page](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC22) mentions that "the Readline library does not have a full set of vi editing functions, it does contain enough to allow simple editing of the line"

Comment: I usually search it by piping `history` command's output through `grep` to get a number for the historic command I was looking for.  But that wouldn't answer the question

Comment: This is ***not*** a vi question; this is a bash question. It’s possible that the users of Vi and Vim Stack Exchange will be able to answer it easily, but it is more on-topic here. Since the OP posted it here, it should stay here. If it doesn’t have a satisfactory answer after about 48 hours, then maybe we should consider migrating it.

Comment: @René Nyffenegger: I’m not sure what Anthony Geoghegan is trying to say in [his answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292967/80216). I interpret it to mean that bash’s vi mode doesn’t support regular expressions, but rather the shell pattern matching syntax (i.e., what you use for pathname expansion (i.e., globs/wildcards) and in `case` statements). If that’s the case, you should be able to search for lines containing `foo` followed by zero or more of any character followed by `bar` — by typing <ESC>`/foo*bar`. But I can’t get that to work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is that you can *not* use regular expressions to search the shell history. According to [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) (the standard for Unix-like operating systems), you should be able to search using regular *shell pattern matching* (as used for filename globbing and with `case` statements). This feature is referred to as [non-incremental search](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC8) but it currently does not seem to be correctly implemented in Bash.

#### POSIX specification

The POSIX specification for shell [Command Line Editing (vi-mode)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_13_03) states that these search patterns should use regular shell pattern matching. While the `^` meta-character is used to match the start of a line, they are **not** regular expressions.

> `/pattern<newline>`
>
> Move backwards through the command history, searching for the specified
>   pattern, beginning with the previous command line. Patterns use the pattern
>   matching notation described in [Pattern Matching
>   Notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13)
>   , except that the '^' character shall have special meaning when it appears
>   as the first character of *pattern*. In this case, the '^' is discarded and
>   the characters after the '^' shall be matched only at the beginning of a
>   line. Commands in the command history shall be treated as strings, not as
>   filenames.

#### Documented Bash implementation

Bash uses the [GNU Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) library to provide its interactive line-editing and history searching capabilities.  The official documentation for the Readline library focuses more on Emacs mode, but a short section in its manual, [Readline vi Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-vi-Mode.html) states that

> While the Readline library does not have a full set of vi editing functions,
>   it does contain enough to allow simple editing of the line.
>
> The Readline vi mode behaves as specified in the POSIX standard.

#### Actual Bash implementation

After a number of experiments on two different systems, I found that the non-incremental searching in Bash/Readline does not work as described in its official documentation. I found that the `*` was treated as a literal asterisk rather than a pattern that matches multiple characters. Likewise, the `?` and `[` are also treated as literal characters.

For comparison, I tried using Vi-mode in `tcsh` and verified that it correctly implements history searching as specified in the POSIX standard.

I then downloaded and searched through the code for the Readline library and found its history searching functions use a simple substring search and don’t use any search pattern meta-characters – aside from the caret, `^` (see [search.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/search.c#n110) from the git repository for the Readline library).

I presume the Bash/Readline developers have yet to implement this feature. I couldn’t find a bug-list but the `CHANGES` files shows that they’ve been regularly fixing issues relating to Vi-mode.

**Update**: This feature was implemented in Readline 8.0 (released with Bash 5.0 in January 2019). As documented in its [CHANGES](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/CHANGES):

> New Features in Readline
>
> a. Non-incremental vi-mode search (`N`, `n`) can search for a shell pattern, as Posix specifies (uses `fnmatch(3)` if available).

Comment: I filed a bug report for this, fwiw: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2016-08/msg00005.html  So.. maybe some year soon (:

Comment: I just stumbled upon my own question... and it is working in bash 5.0.16 (and probably in earlier versions, too)

Comment: @jwd Thanks to your bug report and all the great work of the Bash maintainer and developers, this feature has been implemented for more than a year. :)